# javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory Exception while embedding Undertow with JSF application

Tags: jsf, spring-boot, jsf-2, undertow

I am trying to build a simple JSF web application using embedded Undertow server.

Gradle dependencies for the project:

```
dependencies {

               compile group: 'io.undertow', name: 'undertow-core',    version: '1.4.0.CR3'
               compile group: 'io.undertow', name: 'undertow-servlet', version: '1.4.0.CR3'
               compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
               compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.faces', version: '2.2.11'

}
```

Sample Undertow Server Code:

```
public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ServletException {

        DeploymentInfo servletContainer=Servlets.deployment()
                .setClassLoader(HelloWorldServer.class.getClassLoader())
                .setDeploymentName("helloWorld.war")
                .setContextPath("")
                .addServlet(Servlets.servlet("javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet",FacesServlet.class)
                .addMappings("/faces/*","/javax.faces.resource/*")
                .setLoadOnStartup(1));
        DeploymentManager manager=Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletContainer);
        manager.deploy();
        HttpHandler servletHandler=manager.start();
        PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect(""))
                    .addPrefixPath("/", servletHandler);

         Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                    .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                    .setHandler(path)
                    .build();
            server.start();

    }
}
```

When i start the server,following error comes:

```
Mar 07, 2017 6:04:49 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext
SEVERE: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
Mar 07, 2017 6:04:49 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:239)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:541)
    at HelloWorldServer.main(HelloWorldServer.java:24)
```

Comment: are you sure you included both the jsf api and impl? Or maybe (by accident) only the api?

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje. i am using [glassfish jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11) which includes api and impl both.

Comment: found one issue reported for WildFly Server https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6010

Comment: it is close as 'cannot reproduce',

Comment: Yes. but in my case, it is throwing same error.

Comment: Yes an my suggestion was (almost) identical to the comments in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution.

For JSF bootstrap process we must add Two additional init parameter to Undertow DeploymentInfo class.

1. com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration = TRUE
2. com.sun.faces.expressionFactory = com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl

Also we must add two more extra dependency other than JSF.

1. el-api
2. el-impl

Comment: I have same problem, but these parameters do not resolve it.