# Does Undertow work with JSF?

Tags: jsf, mojarra, undertow

I'm trying to boot-up Undertow with Mojarra, but an exception occurs.
How to fix this error and work with JSF?

[Here is similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42648905/4506703), but this solution does not affect mine.

`HelloWorldServer.java` (refs [Undertow Servlet](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/index.html#creating-a-servlet-deployment)):

```
public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException {
        DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
                .setClassLoader(HelloWorldServer.class.getClassLoader())
                .setContextPath("/myapp")
                .setDeploymentName("test.war")
                .addServlets(Servlets.servlet("FacesServlet", FacesServlet.class)
                        .addMapping("*.xhtml")
                        .setLoadOnStartup(1));

        DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
        manager.deploy();
        PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/myapp"))
                .addPrefixPath("/myapp", manager.start());

        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                .setHandler(path)
                .build();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <undertow.version>2.0.9.Final</undertow.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
    <version>${undertow.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${undertow.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

exception:

```
Jul 07, 2018 9:57:50 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext
SEVERE: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
Jul 07, 2018 9:57:50 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance logNoFactory
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
[WARNING] 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.notNullFactory (FactoryFinderInstance.java:548)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory (FactoryFinderInstance.java:231)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory (FactoryFinder.java:303)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory (FacesServlet.java:524)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init (FacesServlet.java:364)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed (LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start (ManagedServlet.java:300)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet (ManagedServlet.java:140)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call (DeploymentManagerImpl.java:584)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call (DeploymentManagerImpl.java:555)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call (ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call (ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start (DeploymentManagerImpl.java:597)
    at com.github.yukihane.java.undertow.HelloWorldServer.main (HelloWorldServer.java:27)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

Implement same as [FacesInitializer#onStartup](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2.2.8-28/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer.java#L159-L168), so `main` method is like:

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
        .setClassLoader(HelloWorldServer.class.getClassLoader())
        .setContextPath("/myapp")
        .setDeploymentName("test.war")
        .addServlets(Servlets.servlet("FacesServlet", FacesServlet.class)
                .addMappings("/faces/*", "*.jsf", "*.faces", "*.xhtml")
                .setLoadOnStartup(1))
        .addServletContextAttribute(RIConstants.FACES_INITIALIZER_MAPPINGS_ADDED, Boolean.TRUE)
        .addListener(new ListenerInfo(com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.class))
        .setResourceManager(new ClassPathResourceManager(HelloWorldServer.class.getClassLoader(), "static"));
```

2.

Managed Beans are scanned by [`AnnotationScanTask`](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2.2.8-28/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/config/ConfigManager.java#L967-L968) with [`DelegatingAnnotationProvider`](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2.2.8-28/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/config/DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java#L86-L91), that is default `AnnotationProvider` implementation.
Because `DelegatingAnnotationProvider` does not scan root class path (but only `/WEB-INF/classes`(?)), I need implement custom `AnnotationProvider`.

`MyAnnotationProvider.java`:

```
package com.github.yukihane.java.undertow.service;

public class MyAnnotationProvider extends DelegatingAnnotationProvider {

    public MyAnnotationProvider(ServletContext sc) {
        super(sc);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Set<Class<?>>> getAnnotatedClasses(Set<URI> urls) {
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Set<Class<?>>> parentRes = super.getAnnotatedClasses(urls);

        // simplified implementation, without annotations scan
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Set<Class<?>>> ret = new HashMap<>(parentRes);

        Set<Class<?>> parentSet = ret.get(ManagedBean.class);
        Set<Class<?>> set = (parentSet == null) ? new HashSet<>() : new HashSet<>(parentSet);
        set.add(Hello.class);
        ret.put(ManagedBean.class, set);

        return ret;
    }

}
```

`META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.annotationprovider`(refs [`AnnotationProviderFactory`](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2.2.8-28/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/spi/AnnotationProviderFactory.java)):

```
com.github.yukihane.java.undertow.service.MyAnnotationProvider
```

---

Here is complete sources: 
https://github.com/yukihane/hello-undertow-mojarra

Comment: Thanks. Great you found a real solution.

Comment: Yes, my simple example seems working well with both version, 2.3.5 and 2.2.17.

Comment: Ok, But keep in mind that your explicit reference to 2.2.8-28 in the begining of the answer might confuse people that it only works with that version. Please try to improve the answer... Cheers thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Mojarra 2.4.0 **YET**, it is as of time of this posting not released. It had to be put in maven for the transition from Oracle to Eclipse.

http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2018/04/do-not-use-orgglassfish-mojarra-240.html

So use the most recent 2.3.x release (2.3.5 as time of writing)

Comment: Although changing version [2.2.17 and 2.3.5](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.glassfish%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javax.faces%22), both occur same exception.

Comment: Tried adding the two parameters from the post you refer to AND use 2.3.5?